# How can I add virtual column to collection?

Tags: magento2, collection

**I have a output structure of $collection like this:**

[image]

**I have array with sample data:**

```
$arr = [
    'id_1' => 10,
    'id_2' => 30,
    'id_3' => 20
]
```

**I need add $arr to above collection and then i have it's output:**

[image]

**After that, i can filter with price:**

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('price', ['gt' => 12]);
```

**How do I achieve this?**

Comment: From where is the `$arr` value coming from?

Comment: $arr is an array i create with sample data. It contains [id => price] values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I got answer by myseft:**

```
$sql = '(CASE ';
foreach ($arr as $id => $price) {
    $sql .= 'WHEN e.id=' . $id . ' THEN ' . $price . ' ';
}
$sql .= 'END)';

$collection->getSelect()->columns(['new_column_name' => $sql]);
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can have this with the help of joins if the price value is stored in the table.**

```
    /** your main table collection $collection */
    $this->collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['price_table' => $this->collection->getResource()->getTable('price_table_name')],
        'main_table.id = price_table.id',
        [
            'price_table.price'
        ]
    )->where('price_table.id IS NOT NULL');
```

In the above code modify according to your condition and columns name.
I have compared the "id" columns of both the tables.

**If the values are not in the table its in array then do this**

```
$collection->getSelect()->columns(['Column_Name' => '(\'values\')']);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But i just have array $arr, not have second table (same price_table as you)

Comment: check my edited answer, thanks

Comment: I got the answer, thanks you so much!!!